# F# recursive function in strange endless loop

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am very green when it comes to F#, and I have run across a small issue dealing with recursive functions that I was hoping could help me understand.

I have a function that is supposed to spit out the next even number:

```
let rec nextEven(x) =
    let y = x + 1
    if y % 2 = 0 then y
    else nextEven y


// This never returns..
nextEven 3;;
```

I use the 'rec' keyword so that it will be recursive, although when I use it, it will just run in an endless loop for some reason.  If I rewrite the function like this:

```
let nextEven(x) =
    let y = x + 1
    if y % 2 = 0 then y
    else nextEven y
```

Then everything works fine (no rec keyword).  For some reason I though I needed 'rec' since the function is recursive (so why don't I?) and why does the first version of the function run forever ?

**EDIT**
Turns out this was a total noob mistake.  I had created multiple definitions of the function along the way, as is explained in the comments + answers.

Comment: The first sample works fine on my machine.  What input are you giving it and what version of F# are you using?

Comment: I am so far using F# interactive in VS 2012

Comment: You apparently have multiple definitions of `nextEven` available. That's the only explanation for the second function working (and probably for the first one not returning). Try resetting FSI.

Comment: This works fine for me in the same environment.  I copied + pasted the first sample into an F# file, sent it to interactive and then executed `nextEven 3;;`

Comment: Example 1 also works for me from http://www.tryfsharp.org/Create

Comment: Works fine here as well, both from the interactive window and from a built executable. @A.R. Can you try it by itself in a separate project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you have multiple definitions of `nextEven`. That's the only explanation for your second example compiling.  Repro:

```
module A =
  let rec nextEven(x) =
    let y = x + 1
    if y % 2 = 0 then y
    else nextEven y

open A //the function below will not compile without this

let nextEven(x) =
    let y = x + 1
    if y % 2 = 0 then y
    else nextEven y //calling A.nextEven
```

Try resetting your FSI session.

Comment: Yep, that was it, multiple definitons.  Told ya' I was a noob =).